# empty dataframe on merging two dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'HPI': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],'INT': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'IND': [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]},index=[2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'HPI': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55],'INT': [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],'IND': [51, 62, 73, 84, 95]},index=[2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010])

merge = pd.merge(df1, df2,on=['HPI', 'INT', 'IND'])
print(merge)
```

output of the code is
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [HPI, INT, IND]
Index: []

Comment: There are no attribute matches, for example none of the HPI values in df1 exist in df2. Are you trying to [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)?

Comment: thank you sir.....my basics were  not clear

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for concatenate as BERA pointed out.

```
concatenated = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```